# Android Parallax Scrolling

Tags: android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-design-library, android-appbarlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I need to scroll my AppBarLayout and have the CollapsingToolbarLayout collapse using my RecyclerView and have it do a parallax scroll on the child ImageView.

I managed to do this using a NestedScrollView but it hasn't worked with a RecyclerView!

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/leagueDrawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LeagueActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/leagueCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/leagueAppBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

I've tried to make every child of AppBarLayout have a scrollFlag as shown

```
            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/leagueCollapsingToolBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/leagueTopClub"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="260dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/arsenal_squad"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

I've tried to use NestedScrollbar here and it worked but I need a RecyclerView

```
             <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                  android:id="@+id/leagueRecyclerView"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:background="@android:color/white"
                  android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
...
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>."
```

Please help, I've tried to work on adding scrollFlags to every child of CoordinatorLayout but hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your `RecyclerView` really needs to be sibling to the `AppBarLayout`, not its child as you have it. Your layout seems ok otherwise, just move the the `RecyclerView` to the `CoordinatorLayout`.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
         ...
    </AppBarLayout>

    <RecyclerView />
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried that but its still not working. I've got it to work when a CoordinatorLayout is the Root Layout. Now I'm wondering if the CoordinatorLayout can be a child of DrawerLayout and still work with the CollapsingToolbar.

Comment: Yes I have no problem with that.